# Python return is triggering else within previous function

Tags: python, if-statement, triggers

I am attempting to make a simple text based adventure game in python and have come across a small error where an else command is being called when I do not want it to. The following is a small sample from my code.

```
## inventory var ##
 inv=["torch"] 


## inventory function ##
 def ichk():
       print(f" You are carrying{inv}")
       return



##First room, links to a3##

    def a2():
    
    move=input("placeholder text.. You notice an exit to your 'east': ")

    if move==("e"):
            print("You exit to the east")
            a3()
    if move==("i"):
            ichk()

    if move==("q"):
            print("You find nothing of value")
            a2()
    else:
            print("You can't move in that direction")
            a2()
```

When the function ichk() is triggered (by user input "i"), inventory is printed, howver the else print statement is also printed before returning to the beginning of function a2(). I am new to python so I understand that the constructed  argument might not be efficient/effective coding, but I am not sure why this is being triggered.

Thanks to anyone taking the time to read.

Comment: you need to use `elif` Edit: Thanks @Loocid

Comment: @user1558604 That should be `elif`.

Comment: When I add elif to the move==("i") ,the  ichk() function does not return to the calling fucntion. instead it just seem to exit both functions after printing the inventory.

Comment: he means all the ifs after the first should be elif and leave the last else the same.

Comment: Than you, however the 'new' error still remains when ichk() is activated. The inventory prints and now does not return to previous caller a2() at all.

Comment: All sorted. thanks to everyone who responded!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, if you have multiple conditional statements, you need to write them as: if,elif,elif,elif,....,else

```
## inventory var ##
 inv=["torch"] 


## inventory function ##
 def ichk():
       print(f" You are carrying{inv}")
       return



##First room, links to a3##

    def a2():
    
    move=input("placeholder text.. You notice an exit to your 'east': ")

    if move==("e"):
            print("You exit to the east")
            a3()
    elif move==("i"):
            ichk()

    elif move==("q"):
            print("You find nothing of value")
            a2()
    else:
            print("You can't move in that direction")
            a2()
```

Comment: Thank you but by changing this code the return function in ichk() is no longer working. It does not return to previous caller a2().

Comment: Where you have ichk(), change that to ichk(), then a2() underneath. That will run ichk(), then run a2().

Comment: Thank you. this has fixed the problem!.. I am still a little confused as to why my original code triggered the else statement and why I needed to add the function underneath ichk(). My guess is that the return command , returns form the exact point that it was called from. Actually that would probably explain it.

Comment: You got it. Whenever a function is called, python pauses the current function, does whatever that function will do, then when finished will resume the original function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `elif` statements when you chain them like that, otherwise with the input 'i', the 3rd `if` statement you have there will be false and run the associated `else` statement:

```
## inventory var ##
 inv=["torch"] 


## inventory function ##
 def ichk():
       print(f" You are carrying{inv}")
       return



##First room, links to a3##

    def a2():
    
    move=input("placeholder text.. You notice an exit to your 'east': ")

    if move==("e"):
            print("You exit to the east")
            a3()
    elif move==("i"):
            ichk()

    elif move==("q"):
            print("You find nothing of value")
            a2()
    else:
            print("You can't move in that direction")
            a2()
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the elif process. I haven't had any trouble  yet with using multiple if statements in my code (except the inventory). However, changing to elif ended up causing the return statement to exit the function instead of starting from the beginning. Another user pointed out that I needed to add the a2() function underneath ichk(), which fixed the problem. Still learning much about python. 

thanks again for your response.